# Vite with react - Imported function doesn't appear in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, jsx, vite

I'm using Vite with react, and I would like to show in the browser a imported function by `./Components/Navbar.jsx`.

To do this, I created the following script in `App.jsx`:

```
import { Nav } from "./Componentes/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
    </>
  )
}
```

The code with the function (`Navbar.jsx`) is here:

```
import React from "react";

function Nav() {
    <>
        <h1>Navbar goes here</h1>
    </>
}

export default Nav()
```

But the code doesn't show anything in the browser. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function Nav isn't returning anything. Also the return is wrong.

```
import React from "react";

function Nav() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Navbar goes here</h1>
        </>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

Comment: `import { Nav }`  and the OP isn't importing default either.  I would just use `export function Nav()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. use this code in Nav.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
function Nav() {
    return <h1>Navbar goes here</h1>;
}
export default Nav;
```

2. and inport as below in App.jsx:

```
import Nav from "./Componentes/Navbar";
```